# How to diagnose character encoding issue

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding

I am having trouble identifying an issue that seems to be related to strange characters that exist in a Postgres database.  I'm pulling data out of Postgres using Java and loading it into BigQuery.  Occasionally I've noticed that some of the values seem to get changed during the process for no apparent reason.  Upon closer examination, I've found that in all cases the issue seems to be caused by characters that are not what I would consider normal.

The Postgres database encoding is UTF-8.  Java encoding is also UTF-8.

Here is an example of what I'm seeing:

I have a text field that contains this value: `SÅ‚awomir`.

If I run this SQL:
`select length('SÅ‚awomir')`

I get a value of 9 which looks correct.  However, if I export that string to a text file and look at it in a HEX editor (in my case Visual Studio Code using the HEX Editor extension), it looks like the length of that string is 11, not 9.  Upon closer examination, the second and third characters are represented by 2 HEX values rather than just one like the other characters are.  Those second and third characters are represented by the following 4 HEX values:

`C3 85 C2 82`

Here's a screenshot of the HEX editor showing those characters. As you can see, the string seems to have 11 characters, not 9:
[image]

Please help me understand what those characters are and what I can do about it.  Are they valid UTF-8 characters?  If so, why should they get converted by a Java program and how can I stop this from happening?

Update 2023-10-31: Thank you @Laurenz Albe for your response. It makes good sense as an explanation for what happened (and how to prevent it in the future), but I'm not sure it fully addresses my issue because I don't have the ability to control the upstream process that inserts data into the database.

I have a few more details that are relevant:

We use Google Datastream to pull the data from Postgres and move it to BigQuery. When the data arrives in BigQuery, it looks exactly the same as it did in Postgres (which is what I want).  The issue actually occurs when I use Java (JDBC) to pull that value out of BigQuery and then insert it into another BigQuery table.

I don't do this as a single insert statement like "Insert into... select from..".  In that case, the data would never leave BigQuery.  What I do is fetch the data first and assign the results to a Java variable. Then in a second step I insert that value back into another BigQuery table.  When I do this, the data in the destination table gets changed slightly, so I'm trying to figure out how to prevent that from happening.

Here is an example of the original value and the value after being moved to another table:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of that same file in my HEX viewer:

[image]

As you can see, the value has been changed somewhat - the new value seems to be `c3 85 e2 80 9a`

So my issue is really how can I preserve the original value?  There seems to be something happening within the process of pulling the data into Java and then putting it back into BigQuery.  My Java env is configured to use UTF8 encoding, so I'm a bit puzzled as to how I can preserve the original value.

Comment: 1) I get a `length` of 8 and a `bit_length()` of 72, which makes sense as `select bit_length('Å'); 16`. In other words it is a multi-byte character. 2) In your database instance, what does `show lc_ctype'` return? **Add as text update to your question text**. 3) Actually it looks like `Å` is represented by four HEX characters.

Comment: That should be `show lc_ctype;` .

Comment: `C3 85` are the UTF-8 bytes for "Å". `C2 82` are the UTF-8 bytes for the *Break Permitted Here* control character. It is an invisible character allowing a line break without a hyphen (wherever it comes from). Note that `length()` does not return the number of UTF-8 bytes, but the number of Unicode codepoints. The word has 8 visible letters and 1 invisible control character resulting in 9.

Comment: What it *might* be is a double UTF-8 encoding.  Using Python, `bytes.fromhex('53c385c28261776f6d6972').decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` gives `'Sławomir'`.  This can happen if data is sent as UTF-8 but decoded as ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin-1) and then encoded at UTF-8 *again* when sent on.  Neither word translates to anything in Google Translate.  Maybe the latter one is a Polish proper name?  Not easy to fix since bad data already made it into the database.  Fix the upstream problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case of “double encoding”.

The original string must have been “Słavomir”. The second letter (ł) is encoded with the two bytes `C582` in UTF-8.

Now when that UTF-8 encoded string was inserted into the database, somebody set the PostgreSQL client encoding to a single-byte encoding, probably LATIN-1. As a consequence, PostgreSQL interpreted the two bytes as individual characters: `C5` is “Å”, and `82` is an unprintable character, a control character with the name “break permitted here”.

PostgreSQL converted these two characters to the server encoding UTF-8, which turned them into the four bytes you observe. Each of the characters is represented by two bytes in UTF-8.

During the conversion to BigQuery, the “break permitted here” character gets converted to a “curly quote” (‚). What must happen is this:

- the data get extracted with client encoding LATIN-1, so it comes out as `C582`
- the client gets inserted into BigQuery with a client encoding of WINDOWS-1252, where `82` means the curly quote
- the BigQuery server converts the curly quote to ZTF-8 and ends up with `E2809A`

---

To sum up:

- the original data in your PostgreSQL database are already broken, because `client_encoding` was set to `LATIN1` instead of `UTF8` when the data were imported
- during transfer to BigQuery, the data were further mutilated, because the BigQuery client encoding was set to WINDOWS-1252

Comment: Thank you.  I have added an update to the description to better describe the issue based on your feedback (which is helpful).  Any additional insights are appreciated.

Comment: Man, you have a mess.

Comment: The updated question still follows the same pattern. U+0082 is a control character which however [renders as a lower single quote mark e.g. in Windows code page 1252](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#82); a character whose regular Unicode representation is U+201A, which is what you have in the "destination" in the updated question.